# How to make an propertysheet application to facilitate "Closing Apps" action when we restart a machine

Tags: mfc

I am having a propertysheet application and I am doing some operation in it and now in the middle
I restarted my machine then all the applications or closed including my application.Instead of 
forcely closing my application I want to make my application to support something similar to this when I press restart.
[image]

Exactly I should make application support same feature as in the above image.

Can anyone please let me know how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN: The WM_QUERYENDSESSION message is sent when the user chooses to end the session or when an application calls one of the system shutdown functions. If any application returns zero, the session is not ended. The system stops sending WM_QUERYENDSESSION messages as soon as one application returns zero.

You can handle this message in your main window. If there is no MFC macro for this message you can use the ON_MESSAGE macro in the message map.